# How can I bind a data table to a tooltip to show onto a canvas with rectangle elements?

Tags: wpf, canvas, binding, tooltip

I have a canvas element with a bunch of rectangles inside, what I want to do is each time I put the mouse over one of those rectangles I want to show the value of a data table on a tooltip which is not related to the canvas or the rectangles.

[Kinda like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alEJr.png)

Which this code sems to work:

```
<Canvas Name="canvasceldas_phas" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="350">
         <Canvas.Resources>
                 <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="20" />
                 </Style>
         </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

(Basically a tooltip with "20" on it pops out)

But what i want is that insead of an "20" showing up, i want the value of a preloaded data table showing at the rectangle tooltip belonging to the same position as the data table, for instance, I hover over rectangle (0,1), I want the element (0,1) of the datatable showing on the tooltip. (I dont know if I'm explaining myself clear)

I've tried this but doesn't seem to work

```
      <Canvas Name="canvasceldas_phas" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="350">
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding datatable}" />
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Resources>
        </Canvas>
```

Sorry if this may seem obvius or I'm making dumb mistakes but I'm kind of new to wpf and it's driving me crazy
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPF and Stack Overflow. My solution uses tools/methods you may not be familiar with depending on how green you are, but they are very important parts of WPF so you should learn them if you don't already know them.

I would suggest that instead of using a `Canvas` with a bunch of manually placed rectangles, you use an [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netframework-4.8). An `ItemsControl` takes a list of objects and displays each one using a `DataTemplate`.

Take a look at the following code:

```
<ItemsControl Width="500" Height="500">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Height="50" Width="50" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" ToolTip="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Each item in the above `ItemsControl` will be displayed as a `Border` control. All the `Border`s will be placed inside a `WrapPanel`. If you had 100 items, it would result in a grid pattern matching the image you provided. The [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=netframework-4.8) of each `Border` will be the item it's representing, so any bindings will pull data from that item.

My solution would be to use an `ItemsControl` like the above, and populate it with the data from your "data table", where each value from the table is one item in the `ItemsControl`. Then you could bind `Boder.ToolTip` back to the property of that item you want to display.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: mmm, I think I understand what you mean, I have to look how to work with ItemsControl though, but I get the idea, will definetly keep in mind. Definetly there are many different ways in wpf to do similiar stuff. Thank you very much for your answer, helps a lot.

Comment: It's a good thing to learn. `ComboBox`, `ListBox` and `DataGrid` are all types of `ItemsControl`, so learning to master them is an important step. If I answered your question, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).